# Install pylift in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

`git clone https://github.com/wayfair/pylift cd pylift pip install`

I tried installing Pylift package into jupyter notebook like that but its just not working. It gives me the following error

```
  File "<ipython-input-4-68b190c0b799>", line 1
git clone https://github.com/wayfair/pylift
    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It looks like you're inside the Python interactive REPL when you should just be in the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run this on terminal and not inside the notebook. Once you run it and all goes well, you have to restart the notebook's kernel to load the new module.

Ex: *So the module has to do with your computer python libraries while the notebook need to load it for you to use. For that you need to import it (usually in the beginning of your script) as you would do with any other library, so you can use it's functionality.*

Comment: Thank you. Just made it work. I used "pip install pylift" and it worked.

Comment: You 're welcome Despina, mark the question as correct since it help you to solve this and happy python coding.